# Makefile for opening programs

Tags: c++, makefile

How would I go about writing a Makefile that would call, say, gedit hashtable.cpp main.cpp& ?
I know how to use them to compile and make tar files but I'm not sure about this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this would work:

```
.PHONY : all
all: hashtable.cpp main.cpp
    gedit hashtable.cpp main.cpp &
```

Gedit is not really ideal for Make though.

Answer (score 2):

What's the difference exactly? Instead of `gcc` write `gedit` and you're done. `Make` just executes the command in certain order. It is tailored for compilations, for "general" scripting there are much more suitable tools, but you can do it if you wish.